# Multiple Devise Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using ActiveAdmin in my application which uses Devise for authentication. 
I want a single login form for 2 models: Employee and Customer, but upon authentication each should be redirected to a different page. Employees will create login for customers. So no need of a registration form.

Will I have to define my own custom session controller for the above purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by override

```
after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
```

Comment: you have to override session controller for both model as you are having routes for that devise_for :customers, controllers: {sessions: "customer_sessions"} . Now create controller named With CustomersCOntroller inherited by < Devise::SessionsController that and there you can override that after_sign_in_path_for(resource)  method. do same for employee too

Comment: you can use polymorphic association for this functionality.